# Trying to make an android app which changes the xml it pointing to depending on the input

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

So I'm trying to make an app which starts by showing a list of options (1, 2, 3....)
The user then types a number in an input box located at the bottom.
The Layout then shows different list of options. Where the user can input a number again at the bottom.
I tried changing the layout with the click of a button and it worked, but when trying to make it change according to the input, it doesn't.

My main.java

```
package com.example.ussd;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
//import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// This variable is to choose which layout to display
public String position;

EditText etnum;
//TextView tv;
public int x;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//initialize position as 0. This is the main menu

   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 position = "0";
  etnum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
  //tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tve);
  x = 0;

}

//When the button is clicked
public void Clicked(View v) {
//Add what ever was in the edited text to the variable position.
//So if position was 01 and 1 was in the editText, the position would
//now be 011
    position += etnum.getText().toString();
/*  if (x == 1){
    tv.setText(position); 
} */
//If the User types "00" it takes them back to the main menu

if (etnum.getText().toString() == "00") {
    position = "0";
}
//Switches Position. This is uning the variable position which
//holds all the inputs till now to decide which layout to display
switch(Integer.parseInt(position))
{
case 0:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    break;
case 1:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
    x = 1;
    break;
case 11:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1x);
    break;
case 100:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity1);
    break;
case 2:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity2);
    break;
case 3:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity3);
    break;
case 31:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity31);
    break;
case 310:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity31x);
    break;
case 3100:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity31y);
    break;
case 32:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity32);
    break;
case 320:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity32x);
    break;
case 3200:
    setContentView(R.layout.activity32y);
    break;
//If the user enters a number which does not correspond 
//to an option it displays error then removes the last input
//from position (the invalid input they just entered)
default:
    setContentView(R.layout.error);
    position = position.substring(0, position.length()-1);
    break;
}


}
}
```

My xml for the edit text and button (These two elements are exactly the same for all xml files

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" >

</EditText>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/BT1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="Clicked"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="@string/send" />
```

Finally the LogCat

```
12-12 12:24:53.610: W/ActivityThread(28173): Application com.example.ussd is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
12-12 12:24:53.640: I/System.out(28173): Sending WAIT chunk
12-12 12:24:53.670: I/dalvikvm(28173): Debugger is active
12-12 12:24:53.840: I/System.out(28173): Debugger has connected
12-12 12:24:53.840: I/System.out(28173): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-12 12:24:54.040: I/System.out(28173): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-12 12:24:54.240: I/System.out(28173): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-12 12:24:54.440: I/System.out(28173): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-12 12:24:54.640: I/System.out(28173): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-12 12:24:54.840: I/System.out(28173): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-12 12:24:55.040: I/System.out(28173): waiting for debugger to settle...
12-12 12:24:55.250: I/System.out(28173): debugger has settled (1398)
12-12 12:24:55.590: W/ResourceType(28173): Failure getting entry for 0x01080a03 (t=7 e=2563) in package 0 (error -75)
12-12 12:24:55.960: D/libEGL(28173): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libEGL_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so
12-12 12:24:56.020: D/libEGL(28173): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so
12-12 12:24:56.050: D/libEGL(28173): loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_POWERVR_SGX544_115.so
12-12 12:24:56.250: D/OpenGLRenderer(28173): Enabling debug mode 0
12-12 12:25:15.650: D/AndroidRuntime(28173): Shutting down VM
12-12 12:25:15.650: W/dalvikvm(28173): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f11e10)
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3764)
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4383)
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18097)
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3759)
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    ... 11 more
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    at com.example.ussd.MainActivity.Clicked(MainActivity.java:29)
12-12 12:25:15.710: E/AndroidRuntime(28173):    ... 14 more
12-12 12:25:24.470: I/Process(28173): Sending signal. PID: 28173 SIG: 9
```

When I click. Nothing happens. Just nothing.

Comment: Check out my answer and do the changes accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You have wrongly declared the `Edittext` in your `onCreate()` that is why you are getting `NullPointer` exception .

Initialize your `EditText` after `setContentView` as below :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// This variable is to choose which layout to display
public String position;

EditText etnum;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //initialize position as 0. This is the main menu

       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     position = "0";
      etnum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

}
```

Also to get the value of your `EditText` you should write it like `etnum.getText().toString();` not `etnum.toString();`

Do the below changes in your code `Clicked` method to execute.

```
//When the button is clicked
public void Clicked(View v) {
    //Add what ever was in the edited text to the variable position.
    //So if position was 01 and 1 was in the editText, the position would
    //now be 011
    position.concat(etnum.getText().toString());  
    //If the User types "00" it takes them back to the main menu
    if (etnum.getText().toString() == "00") {
        position = "0";
    }
  }
```

Comment: I implemented these changes. Still no response when I click the button. Thanks though :)

Comment: Update your question with the code you have tried. Do you get error still ?

Comment: Done. After changing concat to += Im able to get to activity1, but then the same thing happens again. I'm able to get to a layout once but then it doesnt happen again. The var x and tv are just what i try putting to debug